# Dynamically added link action produces 'This request has been blocked...' error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

When I add category in controller action I return JSON object:

```
return Json(new { categoryName = category.Name, isPrimary = isPrim ? "1" : "-1", categoryId = categoryId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In JS handler function I add item on page:

```
...
var totalLink = "<li style='color: #bbbbbb;'>" + result.categoryName + "<a class='removeCategoryButton' href='#lnk#'>remove</a></li>";

                            var lnk = '@Url.Action("RemoveCategoryFromLocation", "Location", new{locationId = Model.Location.TicketId,  categoryId=-1})';

                            totalLink = totalLink.replace('#lnk#', lnk);
                            totalLink = totalLink.replace('-1', result.categoryId);

                            $('#otherCategories').append(totalLink);
...
```

When I click on remove link I call the following function:

```
$(function () {
            $('.removeCategoryButton').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    type: 'POST',
                    context: this,
                    success: function (result) {
                        if(result.categoryName == 1) {
                            $(this).closest('li').remove();
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

But I get the following error:

```
This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.
```

This error happens only when I add item and want to remove it as soon after add on page. If I refresh page and click on remove link it works without problem.
Just to note when I get the error from above category is removed, so call works it just from some reason pop this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be adding the remove links dynamically and yet you have subscribed to the `.click` event handler only once when the DOM is ready. So make sure you do it in a [*lively manner*](http://api.jquery.com/live/). But since the .live() method is deprecated, depending on the jQuery version that you are using you should use either [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) methods.

So with the latest version of jQuery it is recommended to use `.on()`:

$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeCategoryButton', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'POST',
        context: this,
        success: function (result) {
            if(result.categoryName == 1) {
                $(this).closest('li').remove();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Notice that you no longer need to wrap this in a `document.ready` callback.